# Have one Tomcat application get a bean from another one

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

Currently I have a Spring project that uses Spring JPA to work with data objects and my database. All of it's functionality can be accessed by calling a single facade bean. I want to make a web application based on this data model, but I don't want to extend this project any further. Instead I would like to separate my persistence and service layers from an actual web application layer. That said, I want to package this project into a ".war" file and deploy it on my Tomcat instance. Upon demand from any other application working on Tomcat I would like to have this other application to be injected with the facade bean from my ".war".

I'm sort of new to Tomcat, and googling doesn't really help me much. So here are problems and questions that I have with this concept:

- Is this the right way to do what I want? What I mean is I want behavior provided by my current Spring application to be accessible and reusable by different web applications working on one server. This might be a common case and I would like to know if this is ok as a solution.
- If I have this facade bean in XML context or in annotation context of my project, how can I make this bean visible to any other application working on the same Tomcat instance upon being deployed? What should I write in my web applications to have them wired with this bean? If I want this bean to be a singleton and have all calls to it's functionality synchronized, should I do this through my code/context, or can I have Tomcat somehow take care of this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although you did show some effort on it, as such, your question is off topic. Wouldn't  http://serverfault.com/about be a better choice ?

Comment: @kebs, thanks for the welcome. My question was about how can I design my program, so I really think SO is closer to what I need.

Comment: @kebs This question is entirely on topic here (though the answer is "not possible").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider a REST API approach. You can't do "cross application injection" with Spring and JNDI can be cumbersome to use.

Comment: After some time, selected this as the answer. In fact, I tried to do [this](https://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/) first, but I just wasted time.

Answer (score 1):

Webapps (the things that run in a servlet container like tomcat) are isolated from each other, by design. Sharing may well be a bad idea. However, to share, you can use JNDI. Setting up JNDI in tomcat 7 is described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html). You will need a custom resource factory.

Comment: I am going to look into it today.